# Display checkout ACF Advanced Custom Fields and save the value in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, orders

I am trying to add additional fields to the checkout page. I have setup my ACF fields and can display them on the checkout page (via acf_form), but when I place the order, the values I input in the field does not carry over to the created order.

This is the code I am using to display and update the fields:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_acf_checkout_display' ); 

function my_acf_checkout_display() { 
    acf_form(array('form' => false,'fields' => array('inseam'))); 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta','acf_update_field_at_checkout' );
  
function acf_update_field_at_checkout( $order_id ) {
        
        // acf custom field id
        $my_field = 'inseam';
    
        $acf_form_value = $_POST['acf'][$my_field];
        update_field($my_field,$acf_form_value,$order_id);

}
```

Here you can see how I set up the fields:
[image: Field Setup]

Here's what my checkout page looks like:
[image: Checkout Page]

And here is the "updated" field in the order (which remains empty):

[image: Backend Order Fields]

When I hardcode the value to, say 12, then it works!

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_acf_checkout_display' ); 

function my_acf_checkout_display() { 
    acf_form(array('form' => false,'fields' => array('inseam'))); 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta','acf_update_field_at_checkout' );
  
function acf_update_field_at_checkout( $order_id ) {
        
        // acf custom field id
        $my_field = 'inseam';
        $acf_form_value = 12;
        //$acf_form_value = $_POST['acf'][$my_field];
        update_field($my_field,$acf_form_value,$order_id);

}
```

Does anyone know why it's not populating the entered value for inseam to the order?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Check what you have in your $_POST

Comment: Would you be able to help me with this? I am not very experience with all of this unfortunately

Comment: in your function acf_update_field_at_checkout add var_dump($_POST); to see what data you have from there fix your $acf_form_value = $_POST['acf'][$my_field];

Comment: Ok I really appreciate your help! But I don't think I understand enough to check where this information would show up...I can code in python and java, but have very little experience with php.
I'm using a code snippet tool in Wordpress, which is how I'm injecting the custom code.

Comment: My bad since this will be generated when you create order you need to enable in your wp-config debug and in your wp-content folder you will see new file debug.log where will be saved. Change the line to error_log(print_r($_POST,true)); - read more how to debug here - https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: Amazing that worked! I replaced the string name of the field with the field key mentioned in the debug.log file and then it updated the value correctly.
Thank you so much!
Do you know where I can check the field keys for ACF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the correct Field ID to be used with ACF.

So first in admin ACF Fields group click on "screen Options":

[image]

Then select to display the field "slug" and "Field Key" options.

[image]

Now you can get the correct "Field Key" to use in your code...

So here is the code I have tested, reproducing your settings *(replace in the code the correct **field Key** for your "Inseam" field)*:

```
// Displaying ACF field in Checkout after order notes
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'checkout_display_acf_field' ); 
function checkout_display_acf_field() { 
    $acf_field_key = 'field_648715e6451d1'; // Here set the field Key

    acf_form( array(
        'form' => false, 
        'fields' => array( $acf_field_key )
    ) ); 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'acf_update_checkout_field' );
function acf_update_checkout_field( $order_id ) {
    $acf_field_key = 'field_648715e6451d1'; // Here set the field Key
    
    if ( isset($_POST['acf'][$acf_field_key]) ) {
        $acf_field_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acf'][$acf_field_key] );
        update_field( $acf_field_key, $acf_field_value, $order_id ); 
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Now the field is displayed in The Admin on the order page with the submitted value.

---

**Handling multiple Advanced custom fields** *in a clean way*

First, I have set 2 fields in ACF Field group settings:

[image]

Then Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'checkout_display_acf_field' ); 
function checkout_display_acf_field() { 
    $acf_field_key_arr = array ( // Here set the all required fields Keys in the array
        'field_648715e6451d1',
        'field_64873b2d5f57d'
    );
    
    // Loop through each field key in the array
    foreach ( $acf_field_key_arr as $acf_field_key ) {
        acf_form( array(
            'form' => false, 
            'fields' => array( $acf_field_key )
        ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'acf_update_checkout_field' );
function acf_update_checkout_field( $order_id ) {
    $acf_field_key_arr = array (  // Here set the all required fields Keys in the array
        'field_648715e6451d1',
        'field_64873b2d5f57d'
    );
    
    // Loop through each field key in the array
    foreach ( $acf_field_key_arr as $acf_field_key ) {
        if ( isset($_POST['acf'][$acf_field_key]) ) {
            $acf_field_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acf'][$acf_field_key] );
            update_field( $acf_field_key, $acf_field_value, $order_id ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

The display in checkout page:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for that! Just arrived at that conclusion after hours of debugging :D
If I wanted to display multiple fields, is there an elegant and quick way to adjust the code?

Comment: Just marked it, thank you for the reminder and for the answer again :)
Ah yes, that makes sense, I'll give that a try. Thanks again!

Comment: I have added an addition that uses 2 Custom fields showing how to use an array of field keys and a foreach loop in the 2nd function, that make it clean and compact.

Comment: Tested it and worked like a charm! Thank you so very much for your help!