# add class to woocommerce single product template gallery thumbnails if media attachment ACF field toggled (true/false)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

i have the following custom field (quick_ship):
[image]
[image]
[image]

i've added this in functions but not working at the moment:

```
<?php 

$image = get_field('quick_ship');
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    if( $image ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size, array ('class' => 'quick-ship' ) );
    }
```

Comment: In ACF settings enable the key like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899533/retrieving-related-data-with-wordpress-and-advanced-custom-fields/76900114#76900114) or in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76456726/display-checkout-acf-advanced-custom-fields-and-save-the-value-in-woocommerce/76457676#76457676) and use it. Also, you need to add your code in a hooked function, to get it displayed on the product.

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_image` expect an attachment ID as first parameter. You are trying to pass the value of your true/false field instead.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i have enabled this, it was already. i am not sure how to wrap the current in a hooked function however.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Try to edit your question better explaining things, giving more details about what you are trying to do.